# flutter timing problems on stateful widget after API call

Tags: dart, flutter

I am running into timing problems, I am getting data from a api, then creating a list from the JSON.  I think use the length of the resulting list as the item count in my listview.  However it throws a null error on the itemcount and then completes processing and presents the listview.  I am trying to find where the timing problem is and how items and widgets are processed so that I can avoid the error.  My code is below if anyone has any ideas where my code is flawed.

```
class Specialty extends StatefulWidget {
  Specialty({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _SpecialtyState createState() => new _SpecialtyState();
}

class _SpecialtyState extends State<Specialty> {

  bool _dataReceived = false;
  bool _authenticated = false;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  List mylist;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getPrefs();
    _getSpecialty();
  }


  _getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _authenticated = prefs.getBool('authenticated');
    print('AUTH2: ' + _authenticated.toString());
    print('AUTHCODE2: ' + prefs.getString('authcode'));

  }

  _getSpecialty() async {
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl:8080/support/specialty';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.get(_url);

    var specialties = jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    mylist = specialties.toList();
    //_dataReceived = true;


    setState(() {
      _dataReceived = true;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() {
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new RefreshIndicator(
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
            itemCount: mylist.length,
          ),
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,

        ));
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    Specialties spec = getSpec(index);
    return new SpecialtyWidget(spec: spec,);
  }

  Specialties getSpec(int index) {
    return new Specialties(
        mylist[index]['id'], mylist[index]['name'], mylist[index]['details'],
        new Photo('lib/images/' + mylist[index]['image'], mylist[index]['name'],
            mylist[index]['name']));
    //return new Specialties.fromMap(mylist[index]);

  }


  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();


}
```

Comment: You should have a look at FuturBuilder, which was designed for such purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `await` when invoking your `async` methods. You can mark `initState` as `async`, it will still override.

Make sure to call `setState()` whenever you mutate member variables.

Check `if (mounted)` before `setState` if you are doing it after an async wait, because the widget may no longer be visible.

Consider using [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) instead of `setState` when doing async programming.