# Flutter: How to read preferences at Widget startup?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been trying to read preferences at Widget startup but have been unable to find a solution.
I wish to show the users name in a TextField (which they can change) and store it in preferences so that it is shown as soon as they go back to the page.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller;
  :
  :
  Future<Null> storeName(String name) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString("name", name);
  }

  @override
  initState() async {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _controller = new TextEditingController(text: prefs.getString("name"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  :
  :
  return new TextField(
               decoration: new InputDecoration(
                 hintText: "Name (optional)",
               ),
               onChanged: (String str) {
                 setState(() {
                   _name = str;
                   storeName(str);
                 });
               },
               controller: _controller,
             )
  }
}
```

I got the idea for using async on initState() from :
[flutter timing problems on stateful widget after API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107702/flutter-timing-problems-on-stateful-widget-after-api-call) 
But the async seems to cause this error on startup :

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 967 pos 12: 
'_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not true.
```

I looked for examples of FutureBuilder but cannot seem to find any which are similar to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would suggest not to use the async on initState(). but you can do this in a different way by wrapping up your SharedPreferences inside another function and declaring this as async.

I have modified your code . Please check if this works. Many Thanks.

modified code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller;
  String _name;

  Future<Null> getSharedPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _name = prefs.getString("name");
    setState(() {
      _controller = new TextEditingController(text: _name);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _name = "";
    getSharedPrefs();  
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new TextField(
                 decoration: new InputDecoration(
                   hintText: "Name (optional)",
                 ),
                 onChanged: (String str) {
                   setState(() {
                     _name = str;
                     storeName(str);
                 });
               },
               controller: _controller,
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mahi - your solution gave me the answer. (I modified your code to add the setState() to make it work fully).

Answer (score 3):

`initState()` is a synchronous function where you cannot mark `async`, as `async` convert that function into asynchronous.

Below code helps to load shared preference values at loading time, and used to update widgets.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefValue) => {
      setState(() {
        _name = prefValue.getString('name')?? "";
        _controller = new TextEditingController(text: _name);
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is more cleaner and recommended than the accepted answer.

But, to write the logic on an external method and calling that method in initState is more cleaner, just like the above answer.

Comment: This does not wait the preferences load.

Comment: if you created TextEditingController before then you may use _controller.text = _name;

Answer (score 2):

Doing it at the app-level.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // Rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also User Timer or Future.delayed

First Create Your Method for SharedPreference

```
Future getId() async {
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
id = prefs.getString("id");
  }
```

then in your initMethod

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getId();
    Timer(Duration(microseconds: 250), () {
      _controller = new TextEditingController(text: id);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```