# How can I pass variable from Future<String> to void in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using SharedPreferences i made a simple saver and getter but I want to load my variable **name** when opening app using initState:

**data** is a string with a placeholder

Saver

```
Future<String> saveNamePreference(String name) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('name', name);

  print(name);
  return prefs.getString(name);
}
```

Getter

```
Future<String> getNamePreference() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final name = prefs.getString('name');

  return name.toString();
}
```

Void initState

```
  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    await getNamePreference();
    setState(() {
      data = name;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try - `name = await getNamePreference();` in initState() ?or `setState() => data = await getNamePreference();`

Comment: There is already a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286488/flutter-how-to-read-preferences-at-widget-startup) with the approach for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use then method to do so because initstate complete exaction before data arrives from async method.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getNamePreference().then((name){
       setState(() {
           data = name;
       });
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: I think its best not to keep `initState` as async.

Comment: Definitely, i forgot to remove it. Thanks @AbhilashChandran