# Flutter/Dart - How to Save State when Navigating back to a Form with Textfields?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, state, stateful

Currently, when a user fills in a TextField the text is lost if they navigate away and then return. How can I get the text to stay in the field upon their return?

Here's the stateful widget I'm using;

```
  class _EditPageState extends State<EditPage> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String audiotitle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Container(
          child: TextField(      
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.oldaudiotitle,           
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: (titleText) {
              setState(() {
                this.audiotitle = titleText;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways :

1. store the Data of the text field and set the data in init method
   (use sharedpreferences or any other database as per your requirements)

> ```
> TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
>
>   @override
>   void initState() {
>     // TODO: implement initState
>     // retrive the Data
>     if(data != null) {
>       controller = new TextEditingController(text: data);
>     }
>   }
> ```

or if the first screen is navigating in the second Screen than just pop that screen

> ```
>       Navigator.pop(context);
> ```

Comment: I tried your suggested approach using the selected answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286488/flutter-how-to-read-preferences-at-widget-startup But although it nearly works, it seems to corrupt my shared preferences file. I'm guessing shared preferences isn't too happy about the "onChanged:" function of the Textfield widget.

Comment: when you call to navigate to another screen before that store data in shred pref ( outside of onChanged ) and rest of the calling data init methods seems fine

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that as I'm using a nested BottomNavigationBar to navigate to other screens...